# Get drag shadow position on android

Tags: android

I am trying to record every touch event on my app.
So far i can record every movement and touch events, however when using drag and drop the drag shadow overrides regular move event.
What i would like to know is if there is a way to get x and y coordinates of every movement of the drag shadow.

Answer (score 3):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            mCurX = (int) event.getX();
            mCurY = (int) event.getY();
            mText.setText("Cur(X, Y) : " + mCurX + ", " + mCurY );
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            dragState = "DRAG_ENTERED";
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            dragState = "DRAG_EXITED";
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            if(dragState == "DRAG_EXITED"){
                    DropAction();                       
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
```

Comment: this answer seems to wrong regarding the question. ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION is only fired if the dragged object is within the boundaries of a drop object. And getX()/getY() return the relative position of the drag object within the boundary.